# Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy Boolean or similar

Tags: wordpress

I have created a Custom Post Type: Books.
I have also created a Custom Taxonomy: Printed.

Instead of a category layout or a tag layout that the person using the theme can usually edit, I am trying to set it so that it is  set as a boolean (true / false) without the option for the user to add another category
OR if a boolean isn't available, a string value.

I tried removing the add_new and new_item arrays but they just changed to default so added them back in.

````
   'name' => _x( 'Printed', 'taxonomy general name' ),
   'singular_name' => _x( 'Printed', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
   'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Printed' ),
   'all_items' => __( 'All Printed' ),
   'menu_name' => __( 'Printed' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Printed' ),
   'new_item_name' => __( 'New Printed Name' ),
 );    

// Now register the taxonomy
 register_taxonomy('Printed', array('Works'), array(
   'hierarchical' => false,
   'labels' => $labels,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'show_in_rest' => true,
   'show_admin_column' => true,
   'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Printed' ),
 'default_term' => [ 
       'name' => 'Published'
       'slug' => 'published', 
       'description' => '' 
          ] 


 ));

}```
````

Comment: Why don't you add a custom field instead a category?

Comment: would I be able to get this to display as a boolean or tickbox?

Comment: Definitely yes ,https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

Comment: If my comments has been useful vote my comment and be a good stackoverflower, and post yourself answer. And accept it.

Comment: thanks, not sure how to accept an answer, doesn't give me the option